# Adb command using in subprocess.call with serial no as argument like "adb -s <serialno> install demo.apk"

Tags: python, android, adb

I am trying to pass serial no or UDID of phone from raw_input to my subprocess command.SO that installation to be done in that particular android phone. I am new to Python. Any help would be appreciated.

```
subprocess.call(['adb', 'install', '-r', 'shell=True',  r'C:\Users\bhar\Desktop\Planning\Conn-Android-1.0.88.apk', '-s', 'PDAGAR8872602007'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the order with which you provide the parameters to adb matter. This means that the working call is the following:

```
subprocess.call(['adb', '-s', 'PDAGAR8872602007', 'install', '-r', 'shell=True', r'C:\Users\bhar\Desktop\Planning\Conn-Android-1.0.88.apk'])
```